# Mock location provider not working

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I have picked up Google mock location provider from here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html. I verified that it is indeed providing mock locations by opening Google Maps. The location tracker in maps keeps moving somewhere around Google's office, indicating it is responding to the mock locations. BUT, when I open my own app I do not get the mock locations. I continue to get the real locations. Do I have to make any changes to my app to get mock locations? One more bizarre thing is that even after I shut down the mock location provider , Google Maps continues to receive the mock locations. Only when I restart the phone it goes back to receiving real locations. Any ideas how to proceed? Any other options to test mock locations?

Tested on MotoG (4.4.2)

Edit:

Test code : https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/blob/master/HelloMap3D/src/com/nutiteq/hellomap/HelloMap3DActivity.java
This is just the nutiteq sample app. App works fine, but continues to receive real locations even when mock provider is running.

There is the standard requestLocationUpdates call and then an implementation of onLocationChanged callback.

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: Which code? I AM getting real locations correctly. So that part of code is working correctly, isn't it? It is the mock locations I am not getting. Is there anything I have to change in my app to get mock locations? Wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of using mock locations?

Comment: I am using this code to test: https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/blob/master/HelloMap3D/src/com/nutiteq/hellomap/HelloMap3DActivity.java. The app works fine but continues to receive real locations even when mock provider is running.

Comment: You could develop your own `Mock Provider` like this https://github.com/camptocamp/maps-lib-nutiteq/blob/master/android/src/com/nutiteq/location/providers/AndroidGPSProvider.java ant there you could attach an extern `GPS Device` with a Point Set(i.e. a route) and to ensure, you don't get the real Location from Phone/Tablet GPS, **you can remove the providers you want.** Just then try to display the points, which your own Mock Provider. Regards

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit too hasty placing a bounty. Sorted this by using the same Location Provider "gps" both in the LocationProvider app and in my app.